# Printing Values From A Dictionary That Are Not Zero (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

in a peice of code, i have a class that has multiple dictionaries in it

```
class MemoryClass:
    def __init__(self):

        self.inven_data = {"odcn": 0 ,"odcnamo": 0 ,"charg": 0,"rfl": 0,"rflamo": 0 ,"p_pstl": 1,"p_pstlamo": 5,"ration": 0,"keycard": 1,"room17": 0}
        self.attack_dmg = {"odcn": 15, "p_pstl":2,"rfl":5,"kick":1}
        self.nme_dta = {"nme_hlth": 0,"nme_dmg": 0,"nme_defet":0}
        self.items_left = {"room3": 1,"room4": 1,"room5": 1,"room6": 1,"room7": 1,"room9": 1,"room13": 1,"room14": 1,"room15": 1,"room16": 1,"room17": 1,"room20": 1} 
        self.room_state = {"all_room": 0, "gameflag": 0}
```

i wish to print from the inven_data, but only the values in it that are anything other than zero.

Comment: The syntax you posted is incorrect.  Square brackets denote lists.  Curly braces denote dictionaries.  Please test your code before posting.

Comment: The shown code has incorrect syntax and won't run.

Comment: ok. i will use the actual code from the software as opposed to code that is supposed to fill the function of giving an understanding of what the code looks like

Comment: With method "items()" you can access key-value-pairs of a dict. E. g. in a list comprehension you can then filter out the undesired items and construct strings for output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

keys = np.array(list(self.inven_data.keys()))
values = np.array(list(self.inven_data.values()))

print(list(keys[values!=0]))
```

If you don't want to use numpy, you can use a for loop to iterate over the keys and values.

```
for k,v in self.inven_data.items():
    if v != 0:
        print(k)
```

Comment: This won't work and uses numpy unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks for the check! I fixed the solution. It works now. If the OP doesn't want to use numpy, a manual for loop and if statement can be used.

Comment: The numpy solution wouldn't work because Python lists don't support the operations you apply on them.

Comment: Thanks Michael (I am losing it today clearly)! Edited.